# Photos: some photos get rejected for some reason, why? How to restore them to the collection?

Tags: photo-editing

I am using Polish language version of elementary OS so the terminology might be incorrect. Anyway: I downloaded some free CC licenced stock photos and decided this is a great opportunity to actually use Photos!

It imported the collection nicely and I started to add comments and tags to them so I could find them easier later when I will actually need them for my web projects. But some of the photos get instantly "removed" from the collection when I select them. I double-checked Files and they are "physically" still there. I tried changing the view options of Photos to show "All + rejected" and - yeah - they are here. For some reason they are flagged as "rejected" (or whatever it is called in English).

How to put them back into the normal collection screen? How to remove the "event" meta tags on them?

I tried to reimport them but it says that duplicates where found and they won't be imported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well - it seems that the best way to do it is to remove the photo from the collection. And then reimport it. No duplicates found and I can tag them without problems now. Weird.